# Can't edge slide towards outside

Tags: vertices, edges

I'd like to *edge slide* using <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> key but, it doesn't let me position/click it. I'm using ver3.0. I'm sure I could do this when I was using previous version but, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: it should work if you keep Alt pressed, also try GG then C but don't keep C pressed

Comment: Thank you! I realised one of the problem was that I had 3 button emulate option ticked in my preferences. C worked!!

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you keep <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed, also try <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>C</kbd> but don't keep it pressed

Answer (score 0):

outset now require pressing right alt instead of left alt on blender 4.1 and unfortunately you can't edit this on preferences...